# Accessing shadowed variable from object expression

Tags: kotlin

I have code that looks like this:

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    var number = 5

    val view = object : View() {
        override fun init(number: Int) {
            number = number // ERROR
        }
    )

    // do something with 'number' (and 'view')…
}
```

Of course, the above doesn't compile, because it attempts to assign a parameter.

But what I want to do is assign the outer 'number' variable the value of the 'number' parameter. Is it possible to do this in Kotlin without changing the name of one of them?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do that.

Actually, you need access to the corresponding `scope` (to use this@? = ) and you don't have scope for local function.

I played with

```
    number.run {  
        val view = object : View() {
            override fun init(number: Int) {
                this@run = number
            }
        }
    }

    number.let {
        val view = object : View() {
            override fun init(number: Int) {
                it = number
            }
        }
    }

    with(number) {
        val view = object : View() {
            override fun init(number: Int) {
                this@with = number
            }
        }
    }
```

but none of the above compile: `this` is val and cannot be changed.

Here is the related link:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html